# Availability of Victoria Bitter

Tags: retail-availiability

Is Victoria Bitter (VB) available in the U.S.?  I have not been able to find it anywhere. It was fairly popular in Australia when I was there 15-plus years ago.

Answer (score 3):

I did a quick search and it seems that the brewery's distribution channel to North America dried up years ago. So, no you can't get it from here. But from what I am reading on [Beer Advocate](https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/profile/353/1541/), you should just avoid it anyways since it has an "Awful" rating.